# What's wrong with the default value for a props of a functional component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have no idea, what's wrong with writing the default value of props for a functional component in typescript:

Here is my code:

In `Copywrite.tsx`

```
interface Props {
    siteName: string
    webUrl: string
}

export const Copyright: React.FC<Props> = (
    props: Props = { siteName: 'myWeb', webUrl: 'http://localhost:3000' }
       ) => {
              return (
                 <div>
                    <p>{props.siteName}</p>
                    <p>{props.webUrl}</p>
                 </div>
               )
       }
```

In `App.tsx`

```
const App = (props: Props) => {
return (
    <>
      <Copyright />
    </>
    )
}

export default App
```

I got the error: `Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Props': siteName, webUrl  TS2739`

However, when I set the `Props` interface as:

```
interface Props {
    siteName?: string
    webUrl?: string
}
```

Then, my `App.tsx` won't show the props value on my web page.

What's wrong with my code?

Thanks very much for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the props to the component like so:

```
import React from 'react';

interface Props {
  siteName: string;
  webUrl: string;
}

export const App: React.FC = () => {
  return <Copyright />; 
};

export const Copyright: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{props.siteName}</p>
      <p>{props.webUrl}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

Copyright.defaultProps = {
  siteName: "myWeb",
  webUrl: "http://localhost:3000"
};
```

Comment: I want to set the default value of the `Copywrite` component...

Comment: Here is a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-smoke-5t7uq?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: thanks!  but do you know what's wrong with my code?

Comment: You either need to pass the props from the parent or set the default props as shown...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `props` isn't actually empty: React is supply an empty object for it.

You can destructure and set the default for each prop like below:

```
interface Props {
    siteName?: string
    webUrl?: string
}

export const Copyright: React.FC<Props> = (
  { siteName = 'myWeb', webUrl = 'http://localhost:3000' }
) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{siteName}</p>
      <p>{webUrl}</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```